# Place Autocomplete Fragment, closes as soon as I try and type anything

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-places-api

So yeah, I've set up the API as per a tutorial and I seem to have caught a bug...`
Firstly, I had the issue that the app would crash when I click on the autocomplete fragment,
I managed to moved beyond that with a small fix

```
(private static final String YOUR_API_KEY = "@string/google_maps_key";
```

just inside the class and then

and then

```
if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
            Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), YOUR_API_KEY);
        }
        PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);
```

within onCreate.

I can't moved forward with anything if I can't set a destination. I have set up Google Billing because I've read that this could be the issue but that didn't work either.

```
package com.rizwanqureshi.kevstaxiscanterbury;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;


import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;

import com.firebase.geofire.GeoFire;
import com.firebase.geofire.GeoLocation;
import com.firebase.geofire.GeoQuery;
import com.firebase.geofire.GeoQueryEventListener;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.Places;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.Place;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.PlacesClient;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.listener.PlaceSelectionListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

public class CustomerMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

    private static final String YOUR_API_KEY = "@string/google_maps_key";

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    private Button mButtonLogout, mButtonRequest, mButtonSettings, mButtonHistory;

    private LatLng pickupLocation;

    private Boolean requestMadeBoolean = false;

    private Marker pickupMarker;

    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

    private String destination, requestService;

    //this is the coordinates of the destination the customer is going to go to
    private LatLng destinationLatLng;


    //This is for the dialogue that will appear when a driver has been assigned.
    private LinearLayout mDriverInfo;
    private TextView mDriverName, mDriverPhone, mDriverCar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);


        //check if the necessary permissions have been granted, if not then ask for them to be granted
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(CustomerMapsActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }else{
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }

        if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
            Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), YOUR_API_KEY);
        }
        PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);

        //set the coordinates to 0.0, 0.0, this is done to prepare th
        destinationLatLng = new LatLng(0.0,0.0);

        mDriverInfo = findViewById(R.id.driverInfo);

        mDriverName = findViewById(R.id.driverName);
        mDriverPhone = findViewById(R.id.driverPhone);
        mDriverCar = findViewById(R.id.driverCar);

        mButtonLogout = findViewById(R.id.cma_Logout);
        mButtonRequest = findViewById(R.id.cma_Request);
        mButtonSettings = findViewById(R.id.cma_Settings);
        mButtonHistory = findViewById(R.id.cma_History);



        mButtonLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Signs the current instance of user out and send them to the main activity
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(CustomerMapsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        mButtonRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (requestMadeBoolean){
                    endRide();


                }else{
                    requestMadeBoolean = true;

                    String userID = Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid();

                    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("customerRequest");
                    GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
                    geoFire.setLocation(userID, new GeoLocation(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()));

                    pickupLocation = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
                    pickupMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pickupLocation).title("Pickup Location"));

                    mButtonRequest.setText("Finding your Driver...");

                    getClosestDriver();
                }
            }
        });
        mButtonSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CustomerMapsActivity.this, CustomerSettings.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        mButtonHistory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CustomerMapsActivity.this, CustomerHistory.class);
                intent.putExtra("customerOrDriver", "Customers");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        ///https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#option_1_embed_an_autocompletesupportfragment
        // Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment.
        AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);

        // Specify the types of place data to return.
        assert autocompleteFragment != null;
        autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));

        // Set up a PlaceSelectionListener to handle the response.
        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(@NonNull Place place) {
                // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                destination = place.getName().toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull Status status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
            }
        });

    }
    private int radius = 1;
    private Boolean driverFound = false;
    private String driverFoundID;

    GeoQuery geoQuery;
    private void getClosestDriver(){
        DatabaseReference driverLocation = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("driversAvailable");

        GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(driverLocation);
        geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(pickupLocation.latitude, pickupLocation.longitude), radius);
        geoQuery.removeAllListeners();

        geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                if (!driverFound && requestMadeBoolean){
                    DatabaseReference mCustomerDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Drivers").child(key);
                    mCustomerDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()>0){
                                Map<String, Object> driverMap = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                                if (driverFound){
                                    return;
                                }

                                assert driverMap != null;
                                if(Objects.equals(driverMap.get("service"), requestService)){
                                    driverFound = true;
                                    driverFoundID = dataSnapshot.getKey();

                                    DatabaseReference driverRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Drivers").child(driverFoundID).child("customerRequest");
                                    String customerID = Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid();
                                    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                                    map.put("customerJourneyID", customerID);
                                    map.put("destination", destination);
                                    map.put("destinationLat", destinationLatLng.latitude);
                                    map.put("destinationLng", destinationLatLng.longitude);
                                    driverRef.updateChildren(map);

                                    getDriverLocation();
                                    getDriverInfo();
                                    getHasRideEnded();
                                    mButtonRequest.setText("Looking for Driver Location...");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onKeyExited(String key) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryReady() {
                if (!driverFound)
                {
                    radius++;
                    getClosestDriver();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    private Marker mDriverMarker;
    private DatabaseReference driverLocationRef;
    private ValueEventListener driverLocationRefListener;
    private void getDriverLocation(){
        driverLocationRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("driversWorking").child(driverFoundID).child("l");
        driverLocationRefListener = driverLocationRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists() && requestMadeBoolean){
                    List<Object> map = (List<Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    double locationLat = 0;
                    double locationLng = 0;
                    assert map != null;
                    if(map.get(0) != null){
                        locationLat = Double.parseDouble(map.get(0).toString());
                    }
                    if(map.get(1) != null){
                        locationLng = Double.parseDouble(map.get(1).toString());
                    }
                    LatLng driverLatLng = new LatLng(locationLat,locationLng);
                    if(mDriverMarker != null){
                        mDriverMarker.remove();
                    }
                    Location loc1 = new Location("");
                    loc1.setLatitude(pickupLocation.latitude);
                    loc1.setLongitude(pickupLocation.longitude);

                    Location loc2 = new Location("");
                    loc2.setLatitude(driverLatLng.latitude);
                    loc2.setLongitude(driverLatLng.longitude);

                    float distance = loc1.distanceTo(loc2);

                    if (distance<100){
                        mButtonRequest.setText("Driver Arrived");
                    }else{
                        mButtonRequest.setText("Driver Found: " + distance);
                    }

                    mDriverMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(driverLatLng).title("Your Driver"));
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });

    }

    private void getDriverInfo(){
        mDriverInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        DatabaseReference mCustomerDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Drivers").child(driverFoundID);
        mCustomerDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()>0){
                    if(dataSnapshot.child("name")!=null){
                        mDriverName.setText(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString());
                    }
                    if(dataSnapshot.child("phone")!=null){
                        mDriverPhone.setText(dataSnapshot.child("phone").getValue().toString());
                    }
                    if(dataSnapshot.child("car")!=null){
                        mDriverCar.setText(dataSnapshot.child("car").getValue().toString());
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }

    private DatabaseReference driveHasEndedRef;
    private ValueEventListener driveHasEndedRefListener;
    private void getHasRideEnded(){
        driveHasEndedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Drivers").child(driverFoundID).child("customerRequest").child("customerJourneyID");
        driveHasEndedRefListener = driveHasEndedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

                }else{
                    endRide();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void endRide(){
        requestMadeBoolean = false;
        geoQuery.removeAllListeners();
        driverLocationRef.removeEventListener(driverLocationRefListener);
        driveHasEndedRef.removeEventListener(driveHasEndedRefListener);

        if (driverFoundID != null){
            DatabaseReference driverRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Drivers").child(driverFoundID).child("customerRequest");
            driverRef.removeValue();
            driverFoundID = null;

        }
        driverFound = false;
        radius = 1;
        String userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("customerRequest");
        GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
        geoFire.removeLocation(userID);

        if(pickupMarker != null){
            pickupMarker.remove();
        }
        if (mDriverMarker != null){
            mDriverMarker.remove();
        }
        mButtonRequest.setText("call Uber");

        mDriverInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mDriverName.setText("");
        mDriverPhone.setText("");
        mDriverCar.setText("Destination: ...");
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(CustomerMapsActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(){
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(getApplicationContext()!=null){
            mLastLocation = location;

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(CustomerMapsActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    }

    final int LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please provide permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DriverMapActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/logout"
                android:text="logout"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/settings"
                android:text="Settings"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <Switch
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Working"
            android:layout_margin="10sp"
            android:id="@+id/workingSwitch"/>
    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/customerInfo"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:translationZ="1dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="40sp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/customerDestination"
                    android:paddingBottom="10sp"
                    android:text="Destination: --"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/customerName"
                    android:paddingBottom="10sp"
                    android:paddingTop="20sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/customerPhone"
                    android:paddingBottom="10sp"
                    android:paddingTop="20sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="picked customer"
            android:id="@+id/journeyStatus"/>


    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Any advice would be greatly recieved.

Comment: Do you have Places API enabled on your project? Is your API key restricted? Are you certain that you're using your own project's API key in your app to call the Places SDK?